# How to clear the inverse of a section in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[I have a Square in HTML5 Canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/xqzxawyb/): (Let's assume)

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,0);
context.lineTo(0, 100);
context.lineTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(100, 0);
context.closePath();
```

It is a 100*100 square. In 400*400 canvas, I want to show the 100*100 square and hide everything else. How do I do this?

> Note: I just gave an example of square. I have a complex shape in my
>   canvas which is to be cropped. Other is to cleared. So, I am specifically looking for a crop or a copy to a different canvas and paste back. :) Below is what I am trying to do. I need to keep only what is in the star. Remove everything else.

[image]

Comment: Is your "complex shape" defined in a path command (like the square path command in your example--only your path is more complex)? If yes, then you can use compositing to eliminate all but the pixels inside the path: (1) define your path and fill it with a solid color, (2)   `context. globalCompositeOperation='source-in'`, (3) draw your starfield image. The image will appear only inside the path--everything else will be transparent.

Comment: @markE, I have added the image

Comment: Yep, my suggestion will work for you if you have defined your "star" as a path. Using compositing has a performance advantage over clipping. I have posted my suggestion as an answer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `.clip()` function. You can use `.save()` to save the state to `.restore()` after the clip so it isn't destructive. You can set the path to whatever you would like and it will create a vector mask of that shape.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function () {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 100);
    context.lineTo(70, 200);
    context.lineTo(100, 0);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
}

img.src = "https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d2/m51-400.jpg";
```

[See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7b0qasm/2/).

Comment: Actually, the balls do not come form image. They are from Runtime Canvas. In that case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but the clip method works for fills as well. [Here is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp) to more information about it.

Comment: Just note that with clip you will get jaggy lines in webkit browsers (at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

If your "complex shape" is defined in a path command (like the square path command in your example--only your path is more complex), then you can use compositing to eliminate all but the pixels inside the path:

(1) Define your path and fill it with a solid color,

(2) Set compositing to source-in which will draw new pixels only where existing solid pixels are present and everything else is made transparent.

```
    context. globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
```

(3) draw your starfield image. The image will appear only inside the path--everything else will be transparent.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/water.jpg";
function start(){
  var points=[];
  points.push({x:150,y:0});
  points.push({x:200,y:100});
  points.push({x:250,y:100});
  points.push({x:225,y:150});
  points.push({x:250,y:200});
  points.push({x:100,y:200});
  points.push({x:150,y:0});

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill()

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in'

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Have a time to give a demo by editing the JSFiddle? I would highly appreciate that.

Comment: Sure, I've added example code to my answer. It's almost 3am here so my "star" is a bit wonky shaped, but it illustrates the process :-) Good luck with your project!

Comment: I am using `img.src = canvas.toDataURL();` and this is not working. Any ideas why? Works great with images. and also the `img` is showing the canvas when I append to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
context.fillRect(0, 100, 400, 400);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
context.fillRect(100, 0, 400, 400);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqzxawyb/1/

Comment: Haha! Oops No. I just gave an example of square. I have a complex shape in my canvas which is to be cropped. Other is to cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(0,0,100,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/q776zjdx/

Comment: Haha! Oops No. I just gave an example of square. I have a complex shape in my canvas which is to be cropped. Other is to cleared.